# How would a layout like this be implemented?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am attempting to make an app that will display NHL standings, and want to make something similar to this implementation from theScore.  My original thought was to make something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/teamNamesRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/teamStatsRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

But that would not allow for having the column headers that scroll with the data (as far as I can tell).  How might I implement a design like this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That layout seems like a normal table view. You can implement your table using Androids default TableLayout view or use some library like https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView to approach that.

Comment: I thought that, but wasn't able to find a lot of recent information on the native TableLayout.  Are you able to populate it with a list, like you would with a RecyclerView?  Rather than having 31 <TableRow> tags in the XML?

Comment: I have never used androids table layout but I suppose you can always populate it by adding children to parent with some loop.

`for(..){
   tablelayout.addView(createRow(item))
}`

Comment: It seems very outdated, and the library you linked (which is one I've found before) seems quite robust, so I'll give that a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. You can always modify the library if it don't fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the screen in half and implement a  list view to the left and Horizontal Scroll View to the right

Comment: <HorizontalScrollView ...........>
    <LinearLayout ......>
        <LinearLayout ......>
        //titles
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView/>//put layout weight 1
 </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

Comment: That's almost exactly what I have in my original post, except I used a RecyclerView instead of a ListView